# Solving a complex system of equations with summation

Tags: systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, mathematical-modeling, economics

Could anyone please give any idea on how the following system of equations has to be solved with respect to vector $\hat W$ (which, essentially, contains all the unknowns in the system).

\begin{cases}
\hat L_{i,j} = (\sigma - 1)\sum_{k=1}^9\nu_{k,j}\hat p_{k,j} \space - \space  \sigma\hat p_{i,j},\\
\hat p_{k,j}=\tau_{k,j} + \hat w_{k},\\
\sum_{j=1}^9s_{i,j}\hat L_{i,j} = \beta\hat w_i 
\end{cases}

The model describes change in employment $\hat L_{i,j}$ in region i because of a change in supplies to region j. 
$\sigma, \beta $ are exogenous constants. $\nu$ is a matrix of constants ($\nu_{k,j}$ is a share of region's j income spent on goods from region k), $s$ is a matrix of constants ($s_{i,j}$ is a share of region's i production directed to region j), $\tau$ is a matrix of constants as well ($\tau_{k,j}$ represents costs related to trade between region k and j). $p$'s are prices of goods and $w$'s are wages in corresponding regions. There are 9 regions in total.

I can't figure out the way to find a general solution to the system (preferably, in matrix form, which I can't derive for this system either). Writing them all down doesn't really seem rational since there're like 81+81+9 equations.

If there's no general solution, how do I aproach it then to find vector $\hat W$?
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your system can't be correct with only $\hat w_i$'s as unknown, the second line gives $\hat w_k=\hat p_{k,j}-\tau_{k,j}$ which directly gives $\hat w_k$ but has different values depending on the value of $j$ (I assume).

Comment: It is correct though. The idea is that $\hat w_k$ is the same for all j's within a given i. The second equation in the system is like adding the same change in wage for all regions which buy products from region i. The system can be solved manually (at least a simplified case with 2 regions only, which results in 10 equations) and the solution is correct. Still, it's impossible to obtain a more general one

Comment: What are the other unknowns then?

Comment: There is de facto only one unknown in the system. If we substitute  (2) in (1) we no longer need p's in our equations, and by consequently substituting the obtain (1) in (3) we will only have to solve it for w.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \sum_{j=1}^9s_{i,j}\left((\sigma - 1)\sum_{k=1}^9\nu_{k,j}\left(\tau_{k,j} + \hat w_{k}\right) \space - \space \sigma( \tau_{i,j} + \hat w_{i})\right) = \beta\hat w_i $$

$$ (\sigma - 1)\sum_{j=1}^9s_{i,j}\left(\sum_{k=1}^9\nu_{k,j}\tau_{k,j}\right)+(\sigma - 1)\sum_{j=1}^9s_{i,j}\left(\sum_{k=1}^9\nu_{k,j}\hat w_{k}\right)-\sigma\sum_{j=1}^9s_{i,j}\tau_{i,j}-\sigma\sum_{j=1}^9s_{i,j} \hat w_{i} = \beta\hat w_i  $$

$$ \beta\hat w_i+\sigma\sum_{j=1}^9s_{i,j} \hat w_{i}+(\sigma - 1)\sum_{j=1}^9s_{i,j}\left(\sum_{k=1}^9\nu_{k,j}\hat w_{k}\right) = (1-\sigma)\sum_{j=1}^9s_{i,j}\left(\sum_{k=1}^9\nu_{k,j}\tau_{k,j}\right)-\sigma\sum_{j=1}^9s_{i,j}\tau_{i,j} $$

$$\left(\beta+\sigma\sum_{j=1}^9s_{i,j}\right)\hat w_i+(\sigma-1)\sum_{j=1}^9s_{i,j}\left(\sum_{k=1}^9\nu_{k,j}\hat w_{k}\right) = (1-\sigma)\sum_{j=1}^9s_{i,j}\left(\sum_{k=1}^9\nu_{k,j}\tau_{k,j}\right)-\sigma\sum_{j=1}^9s_{i,j}\tau_{i,j}$$

Now define $S$, $V$, $T$, $\hat{\mathbf w}$ as matrices/vectors where $[S]_{i,j}=s_{i,j}$, $[V]_{k,j}=\nu_{k,j}$, $[T]_{i,j}=\tau_{i,j}$, $[\hat{\mathbf w}]_{i}=\hat w_{i}$, as well as $\mathbf 1=[1,1,1,\ldots,1]^t$ (a column vector of 9 ones) and I think we have (you should check the details)

$$\left(\beta+\sigma \mathbf 1^tS^t+(\sigma-1)SV^t\right)\hat{\mathbf w} = (1-\sigma)S\mathbf 1^t(V\circ T)-\sigma(S\circ T)\mathbf 1$$

where $A\circ B$ is the Hadamard product (element-wise multiplication). This is a linear system but I don't think you can expect to find a general solution, at least it's a simple expression to give to a numerical solver.